# How to create Map<T, List<K>> out of Map<K, List<T> >?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to implement the function:

```
private static <T, K> Map<T, List<K> > invertedMap(Map<K, List<T> > m)
```

For example if I have `Map<String, List<Integer> >` ,

I want to create another `Map<Integer, List<String> >`.

I have written some code:

```
private static <T, K> Map<T, List<K>> invertedMap(Map<K, T> m) {
    return m.keySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> m.get(k)));
}
```

but as you can see this only works if the map in the argument doesn't contain list as values.

Comment: Could you give an example input and expected result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a *stream* way of doing it (though my first instinct itself would be to follow [Federico's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577483/1746118)) :

```
private static <T, K> Map<T, List<K>> invertedMapOfList(Map<K, List<T>> m) {
    return m.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
            .stream()
            .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), v)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't use streams for this (if you want a stream-based solution,  check  [nullpointer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577748/1876620)):

```
private static <T, K> Map<T, List<K>> invertedMap(Map<K, List<T>> map) {
    Map<T, List<K>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // Preserves insertion order 
    map.forEach((k, l) -> 
           l.forEach(t -> result.computeIfAbsent(t, d -> new ArrayList<>()).add(k)));
    return result;
}
```

The above code iterates the input map `map` and for each element `t` of each one of its `List` values `l`, it uses [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to create the result.

`Map.computeIfAbsent` returns the value if there's an entry for the given key, or creates the entry and returns the value specified by its second argument `d -> new ArrayList<>()` (here `d` stands for a dummy argument that we don't need in order to create a new, empty list). Then, the key `k` is added to the list returned by `Map.computeIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
private static <T, K> Map<T, List<K>> invertedMap(Map<K, List<T>> m) {
    Map<T, List<K>> result = new HashMap<T, List<K>>();

    for (K key : m.keySet()) {
        for (T value : m.get(key)) {
            List<K> kList = null;
            if ((kList = result.get(value)) == null) {
                kList = new ArrayList<K>();
            }
            kList.add(key);
            result.put(value, kList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to that suggested in the [answer by  Federico Peralta Schaffner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577483/3182664), except for that it uses `for`-loops instead of `forEach`.  I'm mainly posting this to have an MCVE and a short example the the input/output, but also as a counterweight for the stream-based solution. Now people can argue about readability and maintainability.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class InvertMapWithLists
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> map = 
            new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
        map.put("A", Arrays.asList(0,1,2));
        map.put("B", Arrays.asList(2,3,4));
        map.put("C", Arrays.asList(4,5,6));

        System.out.println("Original:");
        map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

        Map<Integer, List<String>> inverted = invert(map);

        System.out.println("Inverted");
        inverted.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    private static <T, K> Map<T, List<K>> invert(
        Map<K, ? extends Collection<? extends T>> map)
    {
        Map<T, List<K>> result = new LinkedHashMap<T, List<K>>();

        for (Entry<K, ? extends Collection<? extends T>> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            for (T element : entry.getValue())
            {
                List<K> list = result.computeIfAbsent(
                    element, v -> new ArrayList<K>());
                list.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Original:
A=[0, 1, 2]
B=[2, 3, 4]
C=[4, 5, 6]
Inverted
0=[A]
1=[A]
2=[A, B]
3=[B]
4=[B, C]
5=[C]
6=[C]
```